# Flink Kafka connector error in a Maven Scala project, using Intellij, Kafka 0.8.2, Java 7 and Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, maven, apache-flink, intellij-14, flink-streaming

I tried to run the following code.

```
package test

import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{StreamExecutionEnvironment, _}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer08
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema

object FlinkKafkaStreaming {   
        def main(args: Array[String]) {
                val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
                env.enableCheckpointing(5000)
                val properties = new Properties()
                properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "www.iteblog.com:9092")
                // only required for Kafka 0.8
                properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "www.iteblog.com:2181")

                properties.setProperty("group.id", "iteblog")

                val stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer08[String]("iteblog",
                new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))

                stream.setParallelism(4).writeAsText("hdfs:///tmp/iteblog/data")
                env.execute("IteblogFlinkKafkaStreaming")

        }

}
```

But got the following error

```
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-doclet.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/ethan-stream/target/classes:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-scala_2.10/1.0.2/flink-scala_2.10-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-core/1.0.2/flink-core-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-annotations/1.0.2/flink-annotations-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.7/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/force-shading/1.0.2/force-shading-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/kryo/2.24.0/kryo-2.24.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/minlog/minlog/1.2/minlog-1.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.6/avro-1.7.6.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-hadoop2/1.0.2/flink-shaded-hadoop2-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.5/commons-math3-3.5.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.1/commons-net-3.1.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-el/commons-el/1.0/commons-el-1.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/jamesmurty/utils/java-xmlbuilder/0.4/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.7/commons-configuration-1.7.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8.1/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.5/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.6/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-bean-collections/1.8.3/commons-beanutils-bean-collections-1.8.3.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/commons-daemon/commons-daemon/1.0.13/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.2/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-java/1.0.2/flink-java-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-optimizer_2.10/1.0.2/flink-optimizer_2.10-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-runtime_2.10/1.0.2/flink-runtime_2.10-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.4/scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.4/scala-library-2.10.4.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.4/scala-compiler-2.10.4.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/scalamacros/quasiquotes_2.10/2.0.1/quasiquotes_2.10-2.0.1.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-streaming-scala_2.10/1.0.2/flink-streaming-scala_2.10-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-streaming-java_2.10/1.0.2/flink-streaming-java_2.10-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-clients_2.10/1.0.2/flink-clients_2.10-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math/2.2/commons-math-2.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/sling/org.apache.sling.commons.json/2.0.6/org.apache.sling.commons.json-2.0.6.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.27.Final/netty-all-4.0.27.Final.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.2-GA/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.10/2.3.7/akka-actor_2.10-2.3.7.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/config/1.2.1/config-1.2.1.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-remote_2.10/2.3.7/akka-remote_2.10-2.3.7.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.8.0.Final/netty-3.8.0.Final.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/uncommons/maths/uncommons-maths/1.2.2a/uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-slf4j_2.10/2.3.7/akka-slf4j_2.10-2.3.7.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/clapper/grizzled-slf4j_2.10/1.0.2/grizzled-slf4j_2.10-1.0.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/github/scopt/scopt_2.10/3.2.0/scopt_2.10-3.2.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-core/3.1.0/metrics-core-3.1.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-jvm/3.1.0/metrics-jvm-3.1.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-json/3.1.0/metrics-json-3.1.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.2/jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.0/jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.2/jackson-core-2.4.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill_2.10/0.7.4/chill_2.10-0.7.4.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.7.4/chill-java-0.7.4.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10/1.1-SNAPSHOT/flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10-1.1-20160514.040356-150.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-kafka-base_2.10/1.1-SNAPSHOT/flink-connector-kafka-base_2.10-1.1-20160514.040350-150.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.10/0.8.2.2/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/101tec/zkclient/0.7/zkclient-0.7.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/0.8.2.2/kafka-clients-0.8.2.2.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/net/jpountz/lz4/lz4/1.2.0/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/Users/zhenhao.li/.m2/repository/com/yammer/metrics/metrics-core/2.2.0/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.sky.ethan.stream.example.FlinkKafkaStreaming
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/util/Preconditions
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer08.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumer08.java:180)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer08.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumer08.java:164)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer08.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumer08.java:131)
    at com.sky.ethan.stream.example.FlinkKafkaStreaming$.main(Example.scala:32)
    at com.sky.ethan.stream.example.FlinkKafkaStreaming.main(Example.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 11 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I played around it and found out that I couldn't call the constructor FlinkKafkaConsumer08. I used Kafka 0.8.2, Java 7 and Scala 2.10.
What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a version mismatch between the version you compiled your program with and the version you use to run your program. Could you make sure that it is the same version?

Comment: Yes, it is about version difference. How did you know? 
I should use version 1.0.2 instead of 1.1 snapshot

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
   <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.10</artifactId>
   <!--<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
   <version>1.0.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: If you see a `ClassDefNotFoundException` of a core class or a `NoSuchMethodException`, then it is most often the case that there exists a version mismatch. So it was just experience ;-)